# How to add the title of an image in a JQuery serialScroll plugin gallery within paragraph tags?

Tags: jquery, image, serialscroll

I am using the Jquery serialScroll plugin and have made a horizontal gallery which adds a .active class to the the current image. What I would also like to do is get the title of the current image and display it on the page within paragraph tags.

My HTML:

```
<p class="title"></p>

<div id="slideshow">

<ul>
<li><img src="www.website.com/1.jpg title="title 1" /></li>
<li><img src="www.website.com/2.jpg title="title 2" /></li>
<li><img src="www.website.com/3.jpg title="title 3" /></li>
<li><img src="www.website.com/4.jpg title="title 4" /></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

My Javacript:

```
// Easing equation, borrowed from jQuery easing plugin
// http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/


 jQuery.easing.easeOutQuart = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t - 1) + b;
};

jQuery(function ($) {

    var $nav = $('#slideshow li');


    $('#slideshow').serialScroll({
        items: 'li',
        prev: '.prev',
        next: '.next',
        offset: 0, //when scrolling to photo, stop 230 before reaching it (from the left)
        start: 0, //as we are centering it, start at the 2nd
        duration: 1000,
        force: false,
        stop: true,
        constant: false,
        lock: false,
        cycle: false, //don't pull back once you reach the end
        easing: 'easeOutQuart', //use this easing equation for a funny effect
        jump: true, //click on the images to scroll to them
        navigation: $nav,
        onBefore: function (e, el, $p, $i, pos) {
            $nav.removeClass('newclass');
            $nav.eq(pos).addClass('newclass')
        },

    });
});
```

I figure I need to somehow add this Javascript to get the title:

```
<script>
var title = $("li.newclass img").attr("title");
$("p.title").text(title);
</script>
```

Comment: Try to indent the code lines, it would be much easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for that, it has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First correct your html and add the ending quotes and correct the href part like so:

```
<p class="title"></p>

<div id="slideshow">

<ul>
<li><img src="http://www.website.com/1.jpg" title="title 1" /></li>
<li><img src="http://www.website.com/2.jpg" title="title 2" /></li>
<li><img src="http://www.website.com/3.jpg" title="title 3" /></li>
<li><img src="http://www.website.com/4.jpg" title="title 4" /></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

To make the text in the P the same as the title of the picture, use the same function as where you change the class... Like so:

```
// Easing equation, borrowed from jQuery easing plugin
// http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
jQuery.easing.easeOutQuart = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
};

jQuery(function( $ ){

    var $nav = $('#slideshow li');
    var pos = 0;
    $nav.removeClass('newclass');
    $nav.eq(pos).addClass('newclass')
    var title = $("li.newclass img").attr("title");
    $("p.title").text(title);

    $('#slideshow').serialScroll({
        items:'li',
        prev:'.prev',
        next:'.next',
        offset:0, //when scrolling to photo, stop 230 before reaching it (from the left)
        start:0, //as we are centering it, start at the 2nd
        duration:1000,
        force:false,
        stop:true,
        constant:false,
        lock:false,
        cycle:false, //don't pull back once you reach the end
        easing:'easeOutQuart', //use this easing equation for a funny effect
        jump: true, //click on the images to scroll to them
        navigation:$nav,
        onBefore:function(e,el,$p,$i,pos){
            $nav.removeClass('newclass');
            $nav.eq(pos).addClass('newclass')
            var title = $("li.newclass img").attr("title");
            $("p.title").text(title);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the very prompt reply. I tried doing it that way but it seems to stop the entire script from working at all. I'm not sure what is breaking it.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in my code, corrected now. Please tell me what's the error you are getting.

Comment: Brilliant! That works very well expect for one thing. The first image doesn't show the title, it only appears after the first image change. Sorry, I'm not very good with JQuery.

Comment: Well, run the 4 lines in the onBefore function before starting it. with  var pos = 0

Comment: Do I add that after the 4 lines? I've tried a few places and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Thank you so very much, this is a huge help. I've been trying to learn JQuery as much as possible for the little I have needed it and I didn't think I was ever going to get this to work. Once again thanks!